# Is there a way to use Firebase App Check For Huawei Devices or an alternative/combo?

Tags: flutter, firebase-app-check, appgallery

I have created a mobile app in flutter and have enabled Firebase App Check for both Android (Google Play) and iOS (App Store Connect). However, I have been researching the steps necessary to publish the app on App Gallery as well(Huawei). From previous experience I know that the same app bundle is perfectly acceptable by app gallery as well (very simple app - no firebase or other cloud services). However, in this case I have been researching how to extend the app check functionality to include Huawei Devices and cannot seem to find any relevant information. From what I gather from the firebase docs, one solution would to implement a custom Android client implementation **AND** a custom server implementation which seems a bit overkill and also poses other problems (server multi region availability etc).

Does anyone know if there is a better solution/alternative? The ultimate goal is to have firebase app check enabled for Google Play and iOS and something similar ( or a way to use firebase app check ) to authenticate requests from huawei devices.

I tried searching for information on how one can integrate firebase app check with huawei devices. I was expecting this to be a common problem and to find relevant information and implementations. However, I could not find any information or proposed solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Guess a bot miss this time 

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into Firebase App Check to attest apps on Huawei devices, and I don't immediately see any promising [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+%22app+check%22+huawei) for it either.

However it should be possible to roll your own.

1. First, you'll want to research how to [attest apps on Huawei devices](https://www.google.com/search?q=huawei+app+attestation), which (from my quick search) seems to be done through its [Safety Detect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-safetydetectkit/) APIs.
2. Then, once you've attested the app's authenticity, you'll need to [implement a custom App Check provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/custom-provider) to pass the information on to Firebase.

Once you implement it, I'm quite sure others would love to use it to - so please do share any positive results you get.

Comment: Thank you for your help and answer Frank! I will post back if we actually go ahead with this. Since we are a pre-seed startup at this moment, we are evaluating cost to benefit meticulously before deciding to proceed !